# Do we have specific rules when we use four verbs in a sentence?

Tags: gramática, verbos, perífrasis

Do we have specific rules when we use four verbs in a sentence? It is grammatically appropriate to use four verbs in a row in a single sentence? Would this count as a four verb periphrasis?

For example:

> Se ofreció irse comprando al retirarse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Propositions (or simple sentences) in Spanish have at most one finite verb (a verb that is conjugated) and can have non-finite forms like the infinitive, the gerund and the participle. I'd say it's impossible to place an upper limit to these because Spanish, like all languages, is recursive (well, [most of them at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language)), and you can coordinate and nest non-finite clauses indefinitely. That is, you can say things like

> *"Ofreció dejarse observar caminando al salir sin demorarse pensando en volver."*

In practice, you rarely see more than three or four verbs in a row, and these come from combining common patterns of verb + infinitive like *dejar(se)* + infinitive, perception verb (like *ver, oír, sentir*) + infinitive, and verb + gerund like *quedar(se)* + gerund. These phrases become difficult to parse when they get nested into each other, so we break them up. (Something like *"Ofreció dejarse observar caminando"* is about the longest I'd expect to produce or be able to parse.)

A **verb periphrasis** is a different thing. We call something periphrastic when it uses several free morphemes to express a single twist of meaning that could potentially be (or was historically) expressed by inflection. For example, the traditional Spanish passive voice consists of the verb *ser* plus the passive participle of the verb that we want to passivize (just as in English). Latin had a passive voice that was made by simply inflecting the verb. So grammarians call this Spanish passive voice pattern *voz pasiva perifrástica*, because it takes a complex verb phrase to express a single verbal feature. (The other passive voice we have is the *pasiva refleja*.)

Spanish also has a periphrastic future construction: *ir a* + infinitive (*voy a comer, vamos a nadar*). This contrasts with the simple future tense (*comeré, nadaremos*) which is shown by inflection. In this case both forms still exist in the language but they have different functions.

Addenda: I have just noticed that [some teaching materials](https://www.telaquecontar.com/tag/verbo-perifrastico/) call all kinds of verbal constructions "periphrastic". These are patterns using two verbs (sometimes joined by a preposition) that have a special meaning. This is a slightly different use of the term. It's also rather broad, in the sense that it covers so many different types of combinations that it might not be useful except as a label.